# Retrieving MMS _id [android application]

Tags: java, android, cursor, mms

can anyone inform me how can I retrieve MMS _id for the last MMS coming to inbox, by Cursor ? 
thanks

Samiah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Refere this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-beginners/BaqXQUnsKPY)
[and also this](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)